# Looking for a butter dish with space for spreader

Tags: butter, storage, cookware

This is a very specific question .

I like to keep room temperature butter in a small dish to spread on bread or drop into my cooking. I always keep a knife or spreader nearby that I reuse for the butter; I don't like washing a new knife every single time I access the butter. But I also don't like keeping the knife or spreader outside the dish where it may draw the attraction of ants etc.

Do you know anyone that sells a butter dish that has room to keep the butter spreader either (1) entirely inside the sealed dish or (2) with the spreader end inside the dish but the handle sticking out?

Comment: FWIW, if that’s what you’re looking for, buy a [large syringe](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=large+syringe), fill it with butter, and don’t look back

Comment: Find a ceramic artist (that actually forms things from clay, not one of those folks that casts molds bought from elsewhere and paints the results) and explain what you want. As bespoke custom work, expect it to cost a fair amount. Or use a larger covered storage container (big enough to hold knife and butter) which will cost much less.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  I'm not sure if "where do I buy X" questions are allowed on this SE; if your question gets closed, that's why.

Comment: @FuzzyChef they are on-topic, although there were also voices against them.  https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a web search on "Butter keeper with integrated spreader".  Multiple products exist.